# Angular js: Radio button not visible

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, radio-button, angular-services

There are several rows present on the page, in relation to it i have placed the feature of editing values of **every row** after opening a modal popup, now on modal below is the radio button used for Gender.

```
        <input type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.gender" value="{{ctrl.gender}}"/> /*Should be Male with radio button */
        <input type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.gender" value="{{ctrl.gender}}"/> /*Should be Female with radio button */
```

Now here `ctrl.gender` is holding the property either `Male` or `female` returned from server w.r.t that row.

Now i want to edit the property of Gender, by placing a radio button by default that value should be checked what is returned from server w.r.t row, but i am not able to do that and even radio buttons are also not visible

Any advice on this, where i am wrong ..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to refer both value with same scope. You have ng-model right. 
Just try like below.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="ctrl.gender" value="Male"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="ctrl.gender" value="Female"/>
```

Comment: i tried that, but radio button is not visible, and not also the values when i am converting it to text input , i am getting the value returned, hence its sure that value is returned by server

Comment: no errors in console and under chrome elements i can see ng-value as Male and female

Comment: No, all edit fields are under - '<form name="updateForm">'